# Float: left not working with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `float:left` to make a subtitle stay on the same line as a title.

However, when the title breaks to a new line, the subtitle goes to a new line as well.

```css
p {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.other {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  color: #ff442b;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Title goes here.&nbsp;</b>
</p>
<p class="other">Subtitle</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <p><b>Title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here, title goes here.&nbsp;</b>
  </p>
  <p class="other">Subtitle</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The subtitle actually goes to a new line even before the title breaks. Any more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can erase the `float`and use `display: inline` on the `p` tag:

https://jsfiddle.net/eueuo8kk/

(but you should use a class instead of the `p`tag, otherwise this will apply to every `p` tag on the page)

P.S.: I also erased `position: relative` from the subtitle rule. to keep them aligned along their baselines.